# Find if int x is within 10 of closest hundred

Tags: java

Total noob question, but I am in my first Java class and working though a problem set.  I know how to see if a number is in a specific range (posted below) but I am trying to find if this holds true of any of the nearest hundreds.

The rules are N has to be within 10 of either side of nearest 100.

```
if (n >= 90 && n <= 110) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is more math than programming. Consider what `n % 100` looks like when `n` is near `100` (and what it looks like when it's not).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%` operator to calculate remainder of division.

```
int r = Math.abs(n) % 100; // use abs(), or r will be negative if n is negative
return r <= 10 || 90 <= r;
```

Comment: Got it!  I suppose this would also work for any hundred (say 200 or 300) as its just making sure that the remainder is within that range.